# Loop through DataGridView records and stop at the nearest match to my search criteria

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

I have a DataGridView all text values. The user type some text in textbox (txtsearch) and click the button (btnSearch). I want to loop through the values of the column and stop at the first-match / closest match to the text in txtSearch.

Example:

```
PartNum         Desc

PN10  
PN10-1     
PN10-13   
PN12    
PN12-1  
PN12-2       
PN12-3         
PN13-1          
PN15-2       
PN19-1
```

I want when the user types pn12 in the search textbox to loop through the ordered column and stop at the first match , but if user searches for something not on the list like pn14-1 to stop at the closest match "PN15-2"

I know how to loop through the rows and find an exact match

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DGEntries.Rows 
    if row.Cells.Item("PartNum").Value = txtsearch.text then  
      exit for
```

but how to find the closest match. do I have to loop through the search text letter by letter??

Answer (score 0):

Trying to define 'nearest' more rigorously might get you nearer to an answer. For instance, if they were all numeric, you might say that 9996 was 'nearer' to 9998 than to 9990. Once you have a clear idea of what you mean by *nearer* you can calculate a distance for each item in the column. Then it's easy to find the nearest. ie to use my example 9998 gives a distance of 2, while 9990 gives a distance of 6.

Edited in response to comment:

I know it's strings, that's why I said 'if it were'. But you should be able to extrapolate my answer to strings as well. You need to encode your strings into numbers in a way that captures the idea of rank and place order - so that the distance between AA and AD is less than the distance between AA and DA (cf 11 and 14 vs 11 and 41).  For instance, using Base-26 AD would be 1 x 26 + 4 = 30. CA would be 3 x 26 + 1 = 79. Distance between AD and CA is therefore 49.

Comment: its not numbers, its all number-like strings. and the nearest I mean is closest match. Ex: PN14-2 is closest to PN15-2 than PN19-1